# Make Super User Logo Redirect To Certain Tab?

Tags: firefox

I want to make my superuser browsing a little easier, on firefox is it possible to make it so when you click this home button

[image]

It automatically redirects to the tab I use instead of going through questions then newest?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A URL redirect plugin will do what you want.

Download [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) plugin or any URL re-director plugin of your choice.
Set it up like this and you're ready to go.

[image]

The only downside is that you can't access https://superuser.com/ without disabling the redirect as it will always redirect to this https://superuser.com/questions?tab=Newest

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10, you can make a shortcut to that page and drag it to the desktop.

1. Click on the URL.  (It will highlight the URL.)
2. Left click on the highlighted url and drag it to the desktop.
3. When the icon changes so that it has a shortcut icon, release the mouse button.
4. When complete, you will have an icon that looks similar to the following.
   [image]

Comment: sorry this wont help